# После запуска сервера Tomcat при переходе по адресу падает ошибка 404

Tags: java, servlet, tomcat

Создаю свой первый `servlet` и столкнулся с такой проблемой. Сборка проекта в `Maven` проходит успешно, настройки сервера `Tomcat` тоже в порядке. Сервер запускается [image: введите сюда описание изображения], а когда в строке браузера пробую перейти по адресу `http://localhost:8080/test`, должен был сработать мой метод `doGet` и вывести в браузере сообщение `Test!`, но вместо этого вижу:

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report

Message /test

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.8
```

`Pom`файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-b07</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Файл `web.xml`:

```
<web-app>
    <display-name>Simple Servlet Application</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>simpleServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>MyServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>simpleServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Подскажите, что не так и как я могу это исправить ?

Comment: Сервлет мапится в контекст одноимённый с именем war-файла. Попробуйте что-то вроде `http://localhost:8080/servlet/test`

Comment: Sergey Gornostaev, похоже дело в чём-то другом, пробовал и `servlet/test` и `myServlet/test` , в любом случае повторяется ошибка 404

Answer (score 0):

Проблема оказалась в задеплоинном артефакте `servlet:war`, задеплоил артефакт `servlet:war exploded` и заработало так, как мне и надо.

Comment: В ручную что ли через веб интерыейс депозите? Про maven tomcat плагин почитайте